# Can anyone give me example in Real numbers where the outer measure and inner measure are same

Tags: measure-theory

If $E$ is contained in $[a,b]$ then outer measure of $E$ is defined as g.l.b of length of $G$, where g.l.b is taken over all open sets $G$ which contain $E$.

The inner measure of $E$ is defined as l.u.b of length of $F$, where the l.u.b is taken over all closed sets $F$ contained in $E$.

Now my question is In real numbers, give some example where outer measure and inner measure are equal. 
Explain clearly . If $[a,b] = [2,10]$ and if $G =(3,9), E =(3,9)$ and $F =[4,8]$.
Now if we see above the open sets which contain $E$ are $G_{1} = (2,10) G_{2} = (3,10), G_{3} = (3,9)$ then if I take $g.l.b|G_{i}|$(where $i = 1,2,3$) then $G_{3}$ will come whose length is $6$. Therefore outer measure is $6$ and inner measure is $4$. Explain please

Comment: Lebesgue measure does this

Comment: Here's a suggestion to start: come up with an example of your own. Any simple example, not too clever. Figure out the inner measure and the outer measure. Are they equal? If so, why? If not, why not, and can you see how to change the example so the "not equal" part doesn't happen?

Comment: When you have actually made a good-faith attempt to solve the problem, if you still want an answer, edit the question to show your work and what you thought, and maybe someone can help.

Comment: You want an example where it is true? Write out any set whatsoever. If you can exactly express this set in set-builder notation, its outer and inner measure will be the same. It is sets where they are *different* that are difficult to demonstrate, with non-constructive proofs. In particular, it is true for every interval. Which is why it was obvious to David K that you have not made any serious effort to investigate this yourself.

Comment: If [a,b]=[2,9]. And if G =(3,6)  E=(3,5) F=[4,5]  then here F contained in E and E is contained in G and G is contained in [a,b] . Now here outer measure is 3 and inner measure is 1 which are not equal. Please help.

Comment: No, you forgot the end part of the definition "where g.l.b is taken over all open sets G which contain E." you do not get to choose your favourite $G$, you need to consider all of them

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at outer measure specifically (the issue is the same for inner measure).

**You're misinterpreting the role of greatest lower bounds ("infima") here**. We're not looking at the different intervals a single cover, but rather at the different *covers themselves*. Specifically:

- Given a cover $\mathcal{C}$ of our set $A$ by bounded open intervals (for simplicity), let $Size(\mathcal{C})$ be the *sum of* the diameters of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$.
- The outer measure of $A$ is then the infimum *over all covers $\mathcal{C}$* of $Size(\mathcal{C})$.

For example, let's say we take $A=[2,10]$ and $\mathcal{C}=\{(1,8), (3,11)\}$. $\mathcal{C}$ is indeed a cover of $A$ by bounded open intervals, and we have $$Size(\mathcal{C})=(8-1)+(11-3)=7+8=15.$$ But all this tells us is that the outer measure of $A$ is **at most** $15$. By considering another cover we can get a better upper bound on the outer measure: for example, the cover $\{(1,8), (7, 11)\}$ has size $7+4=11$.

And we can do much better than *that*: consider covers of the form $$\mathcal{C}_\epsilon=\{(2-\epsilon, 10+\epsilon)\}$$ for $\epsilon>0$. We have $Size(\mathcal{C}_\epsilon)=8+2\epsilon$ and so $$\inf\{Size(\mathcal{C}_\epsilon): \epsilon>0\}=\inf\{2\epsilon: \epsilon>0\}=8$$ gives an even better upper bound on the outer measure of $A$ (note that we've used a *family of* covers, rather than a single cover, to get this upper bound).

To conclude that the outer measure of $A$ is exactly $8$, however, we need to show that $8$ is also a *lower* bound on the outer measure: that is, that no cover $\mathcal{C}$ of $[2,10]$ can have $Size(\mathcal{C})<8$. Surprisingly, although this may look trivial at first it's actually much harder (the fact that the outer measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is zero, even though $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, demonstrates that this point is subtle - the relevant theorem is the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) together with the easy proof by induction that no cover $\mathcal{C}$ of $[0,1]$ by *finitely many* bounded open intervals can have $Size(\mathcal{C})\le 1$).

---

As a slightly more interesting outer measure calculation, suppose I want to find the outer measure of the set $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$. Now it's worth considering the covers $$\mathcal{D}_\epsilon=\{(0-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon), (2-\epsilon, 3+\epsilon)\}$$ for $\epsilon>0$. Each $\mathcal{D}_\epsilon$ is indeed a cover of $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and we have $$Size(\mathcal{D}_\epsilon)=((1+\epsilon)-(0-\epsilon))+((3+\epsilon)-(2-\epsilon))=2+4\epsilon$$ giving us the upper bound $$\mu^*([0,1]\cup[2,3])\le\inf_{\epsilon>0}(Size(\mathcal{D}_\epsilon))=\inf_{\epsilon>0}(2+4\epsilon)=2.$$ As before, that turns out to be optimal but proving that takes work.

Comment: Your answer doesn't clear my doubt. Finally you have only one open set (2-€,10+€) to cover [2,10]. So any closed set, I can cover with an open set. Please give 2,3 examples. Explain elaborately your outer measure and inner measure.

Comment: @MohammedHakil Do you understand why calculating the total size of a single cover only gives you an *upper bound* on the outer measure?

Comment: I have to give value for epsilon starting from zero, and among all the values i have to take g.l.b.